# Moving string to new paragraph when site is open via mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a strange problem, on my website I have a string, let's say:

```
'contact number 123-456-789',
```

When site is open on mobile device's, the number is split to fit into screen so its looks like this :

```
123-456
-789.
```

Can I somehow display this string in new line when is website is open via mobile?

Thank you for all your help,

Comment: Can you add all meaning code to see the problem and help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your markup so I will give a general strategy.

To avoid the split of the string use:

```css
.short{
    color: blue;
}
.string{
    white-space: nowrap; /*this is the important line*/
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<span class="short">short string </span>
<span class="string">contact number 123-456-789</span>
```

[**Here a working jsfiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/8knmn1ug/) narrow the the result space to see how the `span.string` is display in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the number in a `<span>`:

```
<span class="own-line">123-456-789</span>
```

Then use a media query (css) to force it to drop down onto its own line:

```
<style>@media (max-width: 375px) { .own-line { display: block } }</style>
```